# word warp not working in html despite using break all and break word

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am using below code in my project for wrapping the text but the text is still overflowing to the next text box. I also tried using `word-wrap:break-all` but it did not work. I am using *Chrome* to test my code.

Can anyone suggest what should I use to wrap text in this scenario?

**Code**:

```
<td style="word-wrap:break-word" <%if((sv.ownername).getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ZonedDecimalData")) {%>align="right"<% }else {%> align="left" <%}%> ><%=smartHF.getHTMLOutputFieldSFL(sv.ownername, "ownername", 0)%></td>
```

Comment: You said you are using word-wrap:break-all. But in the code you posted, you are using word-wrap:break-word, which has significantly different behavior depending on the character set. Could that be your problem?

Comment: I have tried both but neither worked in this case .

Answer (score 4):

add this one

```
word-break: break-all;  
white-space:normal;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this html

```
<table width="100" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td><div style="word-wrap:break-word"> 23232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323</div></td>
    <td>abcabc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am still facing the same issue .

Answer (score 1):

You should give width to the text holder so that word-wrap will work

```css
p.test {
    width: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p class="test"> I am using below code in my project for wrapping the text but the text is still overflowing to the next text box. I also tried using word-wrap:break-all but it did not work. I am using Chrome to test my code.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, @shweta can you share your code in Code snippet or JsFiddle so the that we can analyse the code completely.

Comment: Dear @shweta, No need to post the entire code but to analyse the issue we need to reproduce the issue. because the above code works for us. so can you reproduce the word-wrap issue in the code snippet so, that we can give a proper solution

Comment: @ Arun..there is a comma in the text that is to be wrapped.Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had struggled with a similar issue for a while and finally realized that a parent container's height was limited and its overflow property was set to hidden.

After allowing the parent to be taller I finally was able to see the text.

Hope this helps